# Taking variables from string

Tags: string-manipulation, variable

In a mathematica operation I am getting the o/p say, 1->2. For the next step, I want to use these two numbers as variables, say take them as 1 = m and 2 = n. How can I do it.

Comment: `1 = m` is not `m = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
out = 1 -> 2;

{m, n} = List @@ out;

m
```

> 1

```
n
```

> 2

If `out` would be a string:

```
out = "1 -> 2";

{m, n} = List @@ ToExpression @ out;
```